# Zend Framework 2 open graph and single quote rendering with headTitle() -> renderTitle()

Tags: zend-framework2, facebook-opengraph

I trie to render and open graph property with the zend Framework 2 view helper :

In the layout :

```
echo $this -> headMeta()->setCharset('utf-8')->appendProperty('og:title', $this -> headTitle() -> renderTitle());
```

In the view :

```
 $this -> headTitle($theTitle);
```

When i share the page on facebook, the single quote are replaced by :

```
&#039;
```

Any Ideas ?
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the title, it will escape output.  I suspect your issue is that you are passing escaped output into the meta helper.

Rather than doing this at the view level, do it right where you are currently setting title.

```
$title = "One & Two";

$viewHelperManager = $services->get('ViewHelperManager');
$headTitleHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('HeadTitle');
$headTitleHelper->append( $title );
$headMeta = $viewHelperManager->get('HeadMeta');
$headMeta->appendProperty( 'og:title', $title );
```